# How to show Firebird table structure in HTML page?

Tags: php, html, structure, firebird

I try to use the code below to show table structure in a HTML page:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>PHP + Firebird / Interbase test (connection)</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H3>FB Connect test.</H3>
<?php
// DB definition of account
define("DBNAME","xx.xxx.xx.xxx:D:\DATABASE\OCS DATA.FDB"); // data bsse name
define("DBUSER","USER"); // user name
define("DBPASS","USER"); // password

// DB connection
$dbh = ibase_connect(DBNAME,DBUSER,DBPASS);
echo ibase_errmsg();
if ($dbh == FALSE) {
echo 'could not connect to DB<BR>';
} else {
echo 'success to connect to DB<BR>';
}
$ibsql = "SHOW TABLE DOC_TO";
echo ibase_errmsg();
$result=ibase_query($ibsql);
echo $result;
?>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Why does it just show the result as "success to connect to DB"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebird does not seem to have a `SHOW TABLE` or `SHOW TABLES` command which are specific to [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-table-status.html).

The [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20080605115139/http://www.ibphoenix.com:80/main.nfs?a=ibphoenix&l=;FAQS;NAME=%27MySQL%27) on the IBphoenix web site states that the `SHOW TABLES` command is only available in the *isql command line tool* and nowhere else.

> In MySQL, you can do SHOW TABLES. You
> can use the same in Firebird's isql
> command-line tool, but nowhere else.

It goes on and provides the following SQL code as a roughly equivalent solution:

> `SELECT RDB$RELATION_NAME FROM RDB$RELATIONS;`
>
> This query will show you both system
> and user tables. To select user tables
> only, use this:
>
> `SELECT RDB$RELATION_NAME FROM RDB$RELATIONS WHERE RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG = 0;

Maybe you can get something equivalent from what you were trying to accomplish by querying the `RDB$RELATIONS` table (or maybe some other runtime information tables provided by Firebird). See also Lorenzo Alberton's post on [extracting META information](https://www.alberton.info/firebird_sql_meta_info.html) from a Firebird database.

Answer (score 2):

Note than in PHP you should use single quotes `$reqest = 'select ...';` otherwise the `$` symbol will be translated as PHP variable sign.